# group by with repository and entity framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4, repository

i have this entity framework code:

```
repository.GetObjectQuery(Of COUNL1)().
     Where(Function(a) a.CDATE >= '2012/01/01' And 
           a.CDATE <= '2012/12/01' And 
           COID = 88 ).
     GroupBy(Function(m) m.CDATE).
     Select(Function(n) New PointXY With {
        .Y = n.Sum(Function(k) k.TOTALVH), 
        .X = n.First().CDATE}).
     ToList()
```

this error accoured:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

description:
i want group by CDATE and sum of TOTALVH and put it in PointXY Class Like this

```
PointXY {.Y = Sum(TOTALVH), .X = CDATE})
```

sql Query :

```
SELECT        SUM(TOTALVH) AS EXPR1, CDATE
FROM            COUNL1
WHERE        (CDATE >= '2012/01/01') AND (CDATE <= '2012/12/01') AND   (COID  = 88)
GROUP BY CDATE
```

please help me,thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is :

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities.

So go check your `PointXY` class.

If it doesn't have a parameterless constructor... just add one !

```
Public Sub New()
End Sub
```

Comment: use this,but error:The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: @wilsonwilsonpuor well, then... use FirstOfDefault () ?